# How to copy data from cells with specific value to another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am not very familiar with VBA and I need help with programming a code to do the following:

On Button Click in Sheet 1

1. Copy values from Column A if value =1 to  worksheet 2 into column A.
2. If the value = 2 then copy it to worksheet 3 into column A.

This is my current code.

```
Sub Mandat1_Click()
    For Each Cell In Range("A2:A81")
        If Cell.Value = 1 Then
            Sheets(3).Range("C2:C81").Value = Sheets(1).Range("A2:A81").Value
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks in advance ! The task is: 1.In sheet 1 If Column A has value = 1 then Copy columns A,B,D,E,K,R to sheet 2 beginning from A2(sheet2). 2: If in sheet 1 Column A has value = 2 then Copy columns A,B,D,E,K,R to sheet 3 beginning from A2(sheet 3).

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess at what you are trying to do.

```
Sub moveData()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    
    Dim r As Integer
    For r = 2 To 81
        If ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value = 1 Then
            ws2.Cells(r, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value
        ElseIf ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value = 2 Then
            ws3.Cells(r, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(r, 1).Value
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code and it works but unfortunately not as I require it to be. I also need some more updates with it. Could you please help me with it. Thanks in advance ! The task is: 1.In sheet 1 If Column A has value = 1 then Copy columns A,B,D,E,K,R to sheet 2 beginning from A2(sheet2). 2: If in sheet 1 Column A has value = 2 then Copy columns A,B,D,E,K,R to sheet 3 beginning from A2(sheet 3).

Comment: what did you attempt? Provide me the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TransferData()


Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

'Check last filled row
lastrow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then


'Copies data from from Sheet 1 column 1
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Copy

erow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Pastes data in Sheet 2 column 1
Sheets(1).Paste Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(erow + 1, 1)


Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Copy

eerow = Sheets(6).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets(1).Paste Destination:=Sheets(6).Cells(eerow + 1, 1)

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).